# Добавление данных в список пунктов в разном количестве

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recyclerview.adapter

Приветствую!
У меня есть 2 базы данных в первой 100 пунктов и это список глав, во второй более 250 это содержимое глав, мне нужно эти 250 распределить на 100 глав. Например в первую главу 3 пункта содержимого глав, во вторую 1, и таким образом разное количество в разные главы. Я не могу понять алгоритм такой обработки. У меня адаптер возвращает длину масива БД, как мне правильно распределить в нужном мне соотношении?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение:**

Класс БД:

```
class HeadsSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int mDBVersion = 1;
private static final String mDBName = "MYTESTDB";
private static final String mTableName = "TEST_TABLE";

private static final String mId = "_id";
private static final String mLINE1 = "LINE1";
private static final String mLINE2 = "LINE2";

private static final String[] myColumns = {mId, mLINE1, mLINE2};

private static final String myTable =
        "CREATE TABLE " + mTableName +
                "(" +
                mId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                mLINE1 + " TEXT, " +
                mLINE2 + " TEXT)";

HeadsSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, mDBName, null, mDBVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(myTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mTableName);
        this.onCreate(db);
}

List<Heads> getHeadsItem(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(mTableName, // a. table
            myColumns,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    List<Heads> headsItem = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            headsItem.add(new Heads(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mLINE1)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mLINE2))));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return headsItem;
}
```

Класс адаптер:

```
class TheHeadsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheHeadsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Heads> mHeads;

TheHeadsAdapter(List<Heads> headsItem) {
    this.mHeads = headsItem;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.head_items, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
viewHolder.line1.setText(Html.fromHtml(mHeads.get(position).getLine1()));
viewHolder.line2.setText(Html.fromHtml(mHeads.get(position).getLine2()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHeads.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView line1, line2;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        line1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.line1);
        line2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.line2);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, метод

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHeads.size();
}
```

Возвращает всю длину позиций из БД в указанный `RecyclerView` и это список глав где 100 позиций. Теперь задача в том, чтобы я могу в каждую из этих позиций, загружать из другого такого же адаптера нужное мне количество. Например, в 1 позицию глав 3 позиции содержания глав, во 2 - 5, в 3 - 2, и таким образом они разнятся.

Comment: А зачем создавать две базы для Глав и Содержимых глав, неужели нельзя обойтись двумя таблицами?

Comment: Ну это по сути не так важно, для меня главное понять как загружать нужное количество пунктов в нужную главу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать БД определенной структуры, в которой будут 2 таблицы.

Таблица глав Title:

```
| _id | title |
---------------
|  1 | Глава1 |
|  2 | Глава2 |
```

Таблица содержимого Content:

```
| _id | content | id_title |
----------------------------
|  1  | контент1|   1      |
|  2  | контент2|   1      |
|  3  | контент3|   2      |
|  4  | контент4|   2      |
|  5  | контент5|   2      |
```

Таблица *Content* содержит связь один ко многим с таблицей *Title* через поле (столбец) *id_title*, в которой по ID глав устанавливается, какие главы с каким содержимым связаны.

Здесь: контент1 и 2 связаны с первой главой, контент3, 4, 5 - со второй главой.

Далее, после клика на одном из пунктов глав получаем ID этой главы и передаем его во вторую активити для вывода списка содержимого, где делаем запрос в БД к таблице *Content* с выборкой значений, соответствующих полю (столбцу) *id_title* таблицы равным полученному ID главы.

Comment: Как же все просто! Вы гений!

Comment: @McDaggen это стандартный паттерн СУБД (связь один ко многим) известный уже десятки лет и моя заслуга здесь только в том, что я о нем знаю. Если вы хотите заниматься работой с реляционными БД, советую почитать замечательную книгу издательства  O'Reilly за авторством Бейли Л. - "Изучаем SQL"  - 2012г. Где вы сможете узнать все о проектировании структуры БД, типах связей, составлении сложных  запросов и всем прочем в доступной и "живой" манере изложения.

Comment: как раз она у меня на очереди на читку и изучение.

Answer (score 1):

Есть предположение что в базе есть связи по id. Например, содержимое главы и номер той главы в которую оно пишется. Тогда читаем список глав и пишем в список со своими id. Потом читаем базу с содержимым. Берем очередное содержимое и пишем к той главе которая имеет соответствующий номер. Без каких либо связей непонятно как их соотносить. Надеюсь, что помог.