# Создание n-ого количество textView в CardView

Tags: android, kotlin, cardview

Вопрос: 
Как сделать CardView который будет содержать n-ое количество textView? Если я правильно понимаю это кастомный элемент, то есть через код это нужно делать? Сейчас строго указано что всего 4 textView для минут.

Код ViewHolder(a):

```
class ScheduleViewHolder(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_schedule, container, false)) {

@BindView(R.id.textView_hour)
lateinit var hour: TextView

@BindView(R.id.textView_minute_first)
lateinit var minuteFirst: TextView

@BindView(R.id.textView_minute_second)
lateinit var minuteSecond: TextView

@BindView(R.id.textView_minute_third)
lateinit var minuteThird: TextView

@BindView(R.id.textView_minute_fourth)
lateinit var minuteFourth: TextView

init {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView)
}

fun bind(data: TimeViewData) {
    hour.text = data.hour
    minuteFirst.text = data.minuteFirst
    minuteSecond.text = data.minuteSecond
    minuteThird.text = data.minuteThird
    minuteFourth.text = data.minuteFourth
}
}
```

Разметка моего  CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_hour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Hours"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="14 ч." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_minute_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Minute"
        tools:text="10 мин." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_minute_second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Minute"
        tools:text="25 мин." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_minute_third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Minute"
        tools:text="45 мин." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_minute_fourth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Minute"
        tools:text="55 мин." />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Постановка задачи: 
Сделать расписание автобусов. Автобус может ходить сколько то раз в час. Пользователь выбирает остановку и далее с каждым часом в отдельном textView указывается минута, в которые он подойдет к остановке.

Если это важно: CardView отображаются в RecyclerView. Все данные у меня лежат в базе, если это важно, то в Realm.

Ссылка на репозиторий с кодом: [github.com/elsemTim/android-kotlin-bus_schedule](https://github.com/elsemTim/android-kotlin-bus_schedule/tree/feature/realm_assets)

Верстка: 
[image: Как должно выглядеть.]

Comment: Подход не верный,должен быть 1  textView внутри скролаа

Comment: и в него добавляйте столько сколько нужно текстов задавая пробел знаком \n

Comment: @elik обновил вопрос. Добавил верстку. Я не уверен, что ваше предложение позволяет решить данную задачу. Можете прокомментировать еще раз после просмотра верстки?

Comment: да ,пробовали создать фабрику текстов ?

Comment: @elik что за фабрика текстов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в `ScheduleViewHolder` добавить `RecyclerView`, в котором будут отображаться минуты.

Тогда разметка `R.layout.item_schedule` будет выглядит следующим образом:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView             
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_hour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ScheduleScreen.Text.Hours"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="14 ч." />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_stop_minutes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`RecyclerView` сделал фиксированной высоты, чтобы он всех ViewHolder выглядел одинаково.

После этого, внутри `ScheduleViewHolder` необходимо будет создавать адаптер для этого `RecyclerView` и наполнять его. Таким образом внутри добавленного `RecyclerView` может быть любое количество ячеек с минутами.

Answer (score 1):

`CardView` это потомок `FrameLayout`. Соответственно добавляйте в него что надо соответственным образом и делайте верстку какую хотите.

Из вопроса непонятно, если карта должна быть фиксированной структуры (заголовок + таблица 3х5), или динамической (автобус ходит каждые 5 минут, 12 строк без скролинга не влезут).
Исходя из этого и принимать решение об использовании `ScrollView` или еще чего.

Comment: Не со всем понимаю. Структура получается динамическая. Тут я не знаю как лучше уточнить, мне кажется это уже другая задача. Смотрите у нас на остановке А ходит 5 автобусов, каждый из них проезжает разное количество раз за этот час. Я предполагаю, что моя задача отрисовать только минуты, без пропусков, который сделал дизайнер. Просто автобус может ходит в один раз 5 раз, в другой 1. Или рассмотреть другой вариант, где мы находим максимальное количество прохождений автобуса в час и во всех остальных элементах, делаем такое же количество эл. с минутами, но с прочерками. Как идея более правильная?

Comment: Вставьте ScrollView внутрь CardView, дальше задача тривиальная.

Comment: вопрос в том как добавить n элементов в мой CardView? Сейчас добавлю разметку для элемента. Она получается использует всегда 4 textView.

Comment: Так же, как и в любой другой `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @TimurMukhortov Я думаю то что вам нужно, так это поставить в `CardView` один `TextView`, а потом через `RecyclerViewAdapter` этот `TextVew` скажем так размножать в нужных количествах. Вы сможете использовать один `TextView` и он будет иметь какое вам нужно количество в соответствии с данными из БД.

Comment: @McDaggen очень хорошее предложение! Как так можно его размножать через RecyclerViewAdapter? Возможно есть пример, не хотелось бы делать костыли..

Comment: @TimurMukhortov Посмотрите ответа Pavloff тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683676/ и вопрос с ответом тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690888/