# Создание списка с кнопками и последующим выбором

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Доброго времени суток,

Хочу реализовать список, в котором, допустим, сначала выводятся экземпляры одного элемента списка(просто текст), потом элемент с кнопками(2 кнопки), и опять текст.

Прошу помочь реализовать это, или хотя бы натолкнуть на решение.

Примерно так должно выглядеть
[image]

Comment: JavaFX или Swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы использовал RecyclerView и в адаптере к нему переопределил метод getItemViewType. В нем по позиции можно получить элемент и понять какой тип нужно вернуть. Допустим текст это будет тип 0, а кнопки тип 1. Число от getItemViewType передается в onCreateViewHolder и там уже нужно инфлейтить нужную вьюху с нужным ViewHolder.

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам стоит посмотреть в сторону **RecyclerView**, **Adapter**, **ViewHolder**, **CardView**.

1. Мысль следующая, вы делаете свой кастомный **CardView**;
2. Добавляете на свой layout **RecyclerView**, в который будет класть этот этот **CardView**;
3. В вашем **ViewHolder**(e) обращается к вашим виджета, можете их прятать
   (**visible=gone**).

Ссылка на подробный Гайд: [code.tutsplus.com/](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Comment: То есть создать один макет, и просто скрывать когда нужно определённые элементы?

Comment: Да, если вы точно знаете какое количество элементов будет на layout(e) - это достаточно просто и быстро. Если вас интересует конечно, простое решение.

Comment: @EvgeniyDodg Возможно вам покажется интересной ссылка на мой вопрос, он похож. Но там кастомное колл. элементов и есть ссылка того что вам нужно с моей реализацией https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786064/Создание-n-ого-количество-textview-в-cardview